# Exception Handling on the OnError method of the Master Page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I'm having a problem related to the error handling when overriding the OnError method.
In my project I have 10 pages deriving from BasePage and using all the same MasterPage.

Actually I have this structure:

```
 MyPage : BasePage  ==> Generates Exception
```

In BasePage:

```
 protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)  //Get all the errors from derived pages
    {
        var error = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();
        PMIMaster.HandleError(error);
    }
```

In Master Page:

```
  internal void HandleError(Exception e)     //Show the error in a particular label
    {
        AlertMessageHandler.DisplayMessage(exc.Message);
    }
```

The AlertMessageHandler.DisplayMessage(string) simply edit a label and put it visible.

Where is the problem? 
If I call the "AlertMessageHandler.DisplayMessage(string)" from code (without the generation of exception) everything works fine.
If I throw a new Exception if doesn't work as expected: it goes to the BasePage, it reaches the Master and the method exposed... But in the end I have no result.

How can I handle it?

--- EDIT ---
I've done some more research. Actually, even if I clear the exception, during the response the javascript find the same exception (even if it is cleared from serverside). The exception is raised on the method:

```
Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_endPostBack(error, executor, data)
```

And I cannot find a way to avoid it.

I'm allowed to write on the Response object. The response I received is something like:

```
RESPONSE HEADER

Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date    Fri, 10 Jan 2014 07:56:32 GMT
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  80
Connection  Close

RESPONSE BODY

The text I wrote on the Response.Write("TEXT");
```

It seems like that when I update the component I want to see (for instanse write the exception into a label) it is too late for see the operation done..

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using the Application_Error method in Global.asax file? The type of error handling you've implemented (to me) should be a last resort as these are completely unexpected errors. Under those circumstances (again to me) it's better to handle / log the error in Global.asax and redirect to a custom error page to display the error.

Comment: You are right, but I don't want to redirect to a single page, I just want to notify the user that something wrong happened: something like "hey, the age you put in is not right!" or something like that. And I also have pages that uses another custom page, master page, error page and so on..

Comment: For your example exception you should be using the built in asp.net validators not throwing a new exception and catching it in a common method. If there are multiple errors show them in a ValidationSummary control. Remember also that you can do server side validation using a custom validator. Keep things simple and follow standard patterns, your life (and application) will be much easier.

Comment: Ok, I know that, but I want to notify with the same GUI also the exception like "cannot reach database" or "object not set to a reference or an object" so what I want is simply to collect all the exception I get from the pages using the same master page and display them with the same method

Comment: Ahh, I just gave this a go and couldn't quite get it to work. When I throw an exception in Page_Load it handles the error but them seems to stop the page lifecycle and the masterpage doesn't get rendered. I found this article which is doing the same thing but just outputs the error to the screen (no controls). http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages I'm curious now if anyone else can come up with a solution for you.

Comment: From your code sample, it looks a little like you are doing a partial page postback - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm inside an Update Panel

Comment: Then if your master page is writing to a label that is outside the update panel, you will never see this result on your front end.  This would only work for a full postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving the comment from Paddy I've understand the real problem:

- I'm working with all my subpage inside an Update Panel
- My Page tries to update something that is OUTSIDE the Update Panel itself
- I'm not handling the exception in the client side

My solution for the problem is quite easy to understand / realize:

1. Javascript Handling of the partial postback

   function AppInit(sender) {
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endReq);
   }
2. I've handled the endReq method to "remove" the exception from the error stack:

   function endReq(sender, args)
   {
       if (args.get_error() != undefined) {
       var errorMessage;
       if (args.get_response().get_statusCode() == '200') {
           errorMessage = args.get_error().message;
       }
       else {
           errorMessage = 'An unspecified error occurred. ';
       }
       NotifyUser(errorMessage);
       args.set_errorHandled(true);
    }
3. I've written the NotifyUser method that displays the error:

   function NotifyUser(error) {
   $("id of the panel").show();
   $("if of the label").html(error);
   }

So, actually the steps are:

1. Exception!
2. Javascript wrote the exception for the user